# How can I install .deb files for Cydia manually (without wifi)? 

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, cydia

as I already said [here](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/iphone-wifi-problem) my wifi is not working so I need to install Cydia .deb files like SBSettings, Installous, Winterboard etc. manually...well I did, but they wont work properly. I got some .deb files from various website, added them on my device in the cydia install folder, so far so good. I restarted my iphone, the icons showed up (Installous, winterboard) but when I open up Cydia and go to the packages they have a redish background (something like "hey there is something wrong"). Is something wrong with the files or the manual install is not good?

SBSettings -> Respring works, "more" work, the toggle icons don't show up (wifi, bluetooth, openSSH etc). 
Installous -> Added some .ipa files to my device, they show up on download tab on my device but no icons show up (they are blank). I hit install but i get an error like "Error building SBCache" then "Installed" but they are **not** installed.
Winterboard -> works.

So any solution to that problem?
3G 16GB - 3.1.2 - 05.13.04

Answer (score 2):

You can add .deb files and install apps from apptrackr, etc.. using the app iFunbox. I actually just used it the other day to locally upload my custom sms-tone pack. So download your needed .deb files from online, then transfer and install them via the program iFunbox.

http://www.i-funbox.com/

Answer (score 1):

This might be because certain Cydia apps have other requirements. When you download an app from Cydia it checks to make sure that you have the foundational files for that app to work installed, if not then it installs them itself. If you don't have those, some .deb files might not work properly.